# Retrieve Response from Camel Session

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I am working on CSV to Object creation Example with the use of Camel.

I have create a bean in which i have a method with will do all operation, and that method will return List.

My Question is how i am able to get List outside the Camel.

Source Code:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.firstName + "===" + this.lastName;
    }
}



public class UnMarshallingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        // append the routes to the context
        context.addRoutes(new UnMarshallingTestRoute());

        CSVToPerson csvToPerson = new CSVToPerson();
        SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
        reg.put("csvToPerson", csvToPerson);
        context.setRegistry(reg);
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Done");
        context.stop();

    }

}




public class UnMarshallingTestRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:/home/viral/Projects/camel/cxfJavaTest/src/data?noop=true")           
            .unmarshal().csv()
            .beanRef("csvToPerson", "process");
    }
}



public class CSVToPerson {

    public List<Person> process(List<List> csvRows) {
        List<Person> oList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        System.out.println("called");
        for (List csvRow : csvRows) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setFirstName((String) csvRow.get(0));
            person.setLastName((String) csvRow.get(1));
            oList.add(person);
            // doSomethingTo(person);
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            System.out.println(person);
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
        System.out.println("End");
        return oList;
    }
}
```

I have Only Camel Context Object how i am able to get List from context Object.

Comment: usually you would add a `.to()` at the end of your route to send the message where ever it has to go (file, web service, email, etc etc)

Comment: Yes That i know but i need to fetch that list in UnMarshallingTest.Class main Method so that i am able to do some business logic on that list.

Comment: No, you should put your business login in the bean (or else create a processor for it). The whole idea behind camel is that your routes connect 2 endpoints applying various rules and processing along the way. So all of the work required to be done to a message should happen inside the route.

Comment: I dont think so, for example i want to call web service without an input but it will return List<Object> so how i am able to do that. i need to send this List to the caller program. as per your description it not possible because we are calling web service using camel and try to send that output to caller program.So its not possible ????

Comment: Your camel route would also call the web service. Think of camel as a container like a servlet engine. Everything you need to do happens in the context of the camel routes as exchanges. So if you need to get a file, then call a web service and then do some work to merge the data from both operations together and then call something else with the result, that is all happens in the route.

Comment: That means we are not able to get result from Route, we need to do every thing in route it self. if its right its work like standalone application. In my scenario I am expecting data from camel for Example List<Person> lst=camelPersonWebServiceCall(); for web service call i have use cxf of camel. as per your description its not possible at all right?

Comment: Perhaps update the question with your requirements and I will let you know how camel can do it (camel can do almost anything you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one answer for above question.

```
public class UnMarshallingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        // append the routes to the context
        context.addRoutes(new UnMarshallingTestRoute());

        //CSVToPerson csvToPerson = new CSVToPerson();
        //SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
        //reg.put("csvToPerson", csvToPerson);
        //context.setRegistry(reg);

        context.start();

        ConsumerTemplate ct = context.createConsumerTemplate();

        List data = (List<Person>)ct.receiveBody("seda:foo", 5000);

        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("Return Value::::" + data);
        System.out.println("=================================");

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        context.stop();

    }
}

public class UnMarshallingTestRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:/home/viral/Projects/camel/cxfJavaTest/src/data?noop=true")
          .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
            .unmarshal().csv()
            .bean(CSVToPerson.class).to ("seda:foo") ;
    }
}
```

For Consuming response I have use seda. And then after executing route I have consume same, and I get `List<Person>`.